# Sql query to find out experience why we have to divide by 365

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

Display the first name and experience of the employees.

```
select first_name
     , round((sysdate-hire_date)/365) as exp 
  from hr.employees;
```

Why it is need to divide by 365?

Answer (score 2):

Because - when subtracting two `DATE` datatype values in Oracle - you get **number of days** between them. So, in order to get number of **years**, divide that value by number of days in a year which is approx. 365 (but not on leap years, so you might also divide it by 365.25). Or use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function instead.